# How can I install Poppler on Heroku for my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, poppler

I wanted to enable previews on PDFs in Active Storage:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Preview.html

In order to do this I installed Poppler on my Mac using `brew install poppler`. I also installed the Poppler gem in my gemfile. The preview functionality works as I want on my local machine.

When I go to deploy to Heroku the build fails and I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing gobject-introspection (4.0.5), and Bundler
       cannot continue.
       
       In Gemfile:
         poppler was resolved to 4.0.5, which depends on
           gio2 was resolved to 4.0.5, which depends on
             gobject-introspection
```

I've attempted using the following buildpack, but with no luck:
https://github.com/amitree/heroku-buildpack-poppler.git

Has anyone had any success installing Poppler on Heroku? Ideally on more recent Heroku stacks, and not an older stack.

Comment: Sorry deleted my comment as I suggested the exact same buildpack you mention in your post. Another solution is using an image tool such as VIPS or ImageMagick. ImageMagick is definitely included in Heroku stacks. VIPS probably also from 22 stack.. Basically you have to transform the first page of your PDF into Jpeg then store it somewhere. I use Shrine / AWS S3 to do that but there are many solutions.